# How do you filter a sharepoint data source table (list) by months with a drop-down menu

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I am having issues filtering my companies SharePoint DataSource table using a drop-down menu with hard coded months in said drop down menu. I've been told that I have to use PowerApps to filter a datasource of graduation dates so that way the start date for each graduation shows up in the click of a button through the drop down menu that has the hard coded months of the year so that way only the graduation events for that specific month show up ( EX: January shows 5 events starting in that month or may show 15 events showing in that month etc).

I am having issues with the drop-down menu in the sense that I want to statically assign months in the items section of the menu and then I want to attach those static months to a SharePoint list and let those static months act as options for the SharePoint data that I linked with dependent drop-down.

[TLDR: I can either hard code the months of the year in a drop-down menu and have no connection with the data source list or I can connect with the datasource and even choose the column for the drop-down list, but it won't let me actually filter the data source and it won't let me use my hard coded month items]

for example: Say I have a column that lists the created date of a graduation event on SharePoint and while I could use a dependent drop-down menu which satisfies the linking data part but not the filtering data part using months of the year as static options.

if any clarification is needed let me know as I am lost since this list is a work list and I can't edit it due to reasons I can't explain.

[ True TLDR: it's either one or the other in terms of having a functional drop-down box as I have tried a decent amount of formula combinations with sort and filter but sadly my knowledge is limited in powerapps and I was sprung with this project]

Answer (score 0):

How about you use a static table like `[{ name: "January", serial: 1},...]` for your dropdown. The `name` field is to be displayed to the users.
Then you can filter your data source with expressions like `Filter(GradDates,Month(StartDate)=Dropdown.Selected.serial)`